# Strengths and weaknesses of XmlBlaster

Tags: java, xml, message-queue, messaging, xmlblaster

Are/were you using XmlBlaster? What do you think about it? What are its weaknesses and strengths?

Answer (score 1):

What are your requirements? Discussing middleware without concrete requirements is a bit like comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i think i was clear. i was asking about strengths and weaknesses - for such a question, no requirements needed. one comes and says for example "in x situation, xmlblaster is so baad". that's all i want